# Directorio Colaborativo

Tags: linux

Estoy tratando de crear un directorio colaborativo en linux, fue creado el directorio `/nfsdata`, se creo el grupo nfsgrp, se crearon los usuarios `user1` y `user2` perteneciente al grupo `nfsgrp`.

```
chmod 2770 /nfsdata
drwxrws---. 2 nfsnobody nfsgrp 19 Sep  2 08:42 /nfsdata/
```

Cuendo los usuarios `user1` y `user2` crean archivos el grupo dueño de estos archivos es `nfsgrp` pero el permiso del grupo es de solo lectura, se supone que el permiso también debe ser heredado del grupo para que otros usuarios perteneciente al grupo lo puedan editar pero no sé por qué se crea de solo lectura:

```
[user1@server1 nfsdata]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 user1 nfsgrp 0 Sep  2 08:53 aaa
-rw-r--r--. 1 user1 nfsgrp 0 Sep  2 08:42 user1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user2 nfsgrp 0 Sep  2 08:50 user2
[user1@server1 nfsdata]$
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estuve haciendo algo mal durente el procedimiento de creacion de los usuarios, los usuarios fueron creados teniendo como grupo primario el grupo colaborativo(nfsgrp), fue creado un tercer usuario teniendo como grupo secundario el grupo nfsgrp y ahora si veo el resultado esperado.

Saludos